Error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase: KMS.NotFoundException: Key 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:key/xxxxx' does not exist
I am using aws codebuild, where my source is "codecommit" and trying to upload artifact to S3. But getting below exception. I'm using a cross-account codepipeline and at build time it throws this error. The KMS already exists along with the role configurations
